# Show that $ \binom{n}{i\;j\;k} \le \binom{n}{m\;m\;m} $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, factorial, multinomial-coefficients

Is it true that for integers $i+j+k= 3m = n$ where $i , j, k , m , n\ge 0$ the inequality holds ?
$$
\binom{n}{i\;j\;k} \le \binom{n}{m\;m\;m}
$$
I tried to show
$$
 \frac{n!}{m!m!m!} \Big/ \frac{n!}{i!j!k!} = \frac{i!j!k!}{m!m!m!} \ge 1 
$$
but I have no idea how to proceed , are there any related theorems  ?

Comment: I wonder if there is a combinatorial explanation of this inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $i!j!k!\geq (m!)^3$, as you have noted. Consider using Jensens inequality on the convex function $\ln(x!)$:
$$f(\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^nx_n)\leq \frac1n\sum_{k=0}^nf(x_n)$$
$$\ln((\frac{i+j+k}3)!)\leq \frac13(\ln(i!)+\ln(j!)+\ln(k!))$$
$$3\ln(m!)\leq \ln(i!j!k!)$$
$$(m!)^3\leq i!j!k!$$
Proven as required. Note that the concavity of $\ln(x!)$ can be quickly proven via the definition of a factorial.

Comment: Is $\ln x!$ considered here as a concave function of a natural number argument or a real argument (i.e. $\ln\Gamma(x+1)$)?

Comment: Should be convex, not concave. @StinkingBishop Does it matter? If it's convex on naturals, then we can just connect the values linearly to non-negative reals and get a convex real function, no? Without needing to consider $\Gamma$ or anything.

Comment: Oh oops my bad this is what happens when I do math at 1 am, I’ll fix it. Also yes I do usually use factorial and gamma function to be interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

Sketch of the proof...

Start with $(i+1)!(j-1)!=i!j!\frac{i+1}{j}< i!j!$ if $i+1<j$. thus, whenever some of the numbers $i,j,k$ differ by at least $2$, you can replace them with (smaller $+1$, bigger $-1$), without changing the total sum $i+j+k$, and get the product of the factorials smaller. So the product of factorials is the smallest (for the given sum $n=3m$) when the difference between any of $i, j, k$ is at most $1$.

Now note that sum of three numbers $i, j, k$ is divisible by $3$ only if either they all give the same remainder in division by $3$ or all give different remainders. The second case implies that at least two of them would differ by at least two. The first case, together with all them having differences between each other at most $1$, implies that they are all equal. Thus, the smallest product $i!j!k!$ with $i+j+k=n=3m$ occurs when $i=j=k=m$.

Comment: I understand better with this . Suppose $i,j,k$ minimizes $i!j!k!$ given $n=3m$ . 
Let A: "The inequlity  exists" , B: "Any $i,j,k$ differ by at least 2" , C: " $i+j+k$ divisible by 3" , D: "all i/3 , j/3 ,k/3 give the same remainder" , E: "all i/3 , j/3 ,k/3 give the different remainders"" , G: "$i=j=k=m$" . 
We have 2 relationships that're always true: A$\implies$ ~B and C$\implies$D$\vee$E . In this problem we are given that A$\equiv$T and C$\equiv$T , so ~B$\wedge$(D$\vee$E)$\equiv$ ~B$\wedge$D$\vee$F $\equiv$ G$\vee$F $\equiv$ G $\equiv$ T .